# bin/sh: 1: webpack: not found

Tags: docker, webpack, cypress, circleci

I'm trying to add Cypress tests to the CircleCI pipeline. So I used a [Cypress docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/base) in my **config.yml** file:

```
docker:
    - image: cypress/base:12
```

The Cypress tests run successfully when a commit is made and the CircleCI build is triggered. But `yarn build` which executes `NODE_ENV=production webpack` will fail with the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ NODE_ENV=production webpack
/bin/sh: 1: webpack: not found
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Exited with code exit status 127
CircleCI received exit code 127
```

webpack and webpack-related packages are locally installed as devDependencies.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe run `yarn install`? Installing anything locally doesn't make it available in a container